# Somatória de Horas Positivas e Negativas Totais

Tags: php

Preciso realizar a somatória de horas positivas e negativas para um controle de ponto eletrônico virtual. Porém, estou tendo dificuldades para realizar a soma, pois não está sendo somado corretamente as horas, e quando é somado, está sendo parametrizado as horas do dia e não as horas totais.

Meu código já me traz as horas de cada batida de ponto eletrônico e consigo resgatar os horários de batida de cada dia e imprimir na tela sem problemas. O que não consigo, é somar as horas que excederam o expediente de trabalho dos funcionários (a lógica para cálculo de horas excedentes também funciona perfeitamente).

Vamos ao problema.
1- Essa é a tabela do HTML que imprime os valores:

```
ID | Excedentes |
1  |  - 03:00   |
2  |  + 00:14   |
3  |  + 00:20   |
4  |  - 01:24   |
5  |  - 00:02   |
6  |  + 00:01   |
---|------------|

Total Positivo que está trazendo: + 00:01
//O correto seria trazer + 00:35 (com base nestes dados informados)

Total Negativo que está trazendo: - 11:26
//O correto seria trazer - 04:26 (com base nestes dados informados)
```

**Vale ressaltar que as horas podem ultrapassar 24 horas, pois preciso saber o somatório total.**

2- Este é o código que armazena a hora resgatada do banco de dados (utilizei uma variável global para ficar mais fácil de resgatar em tela na tag PHP):

```
/*Acima desse código existe todas as tratativas que funciona corretamente
 para armazenar, resgatar e imprimir os dados na tela, apenas crio uma
variável global para armazenar o valor (pois o mesmo está dentro de um loop,
e cada vez que passa pelo loop, naturalmente o valor muda)*/

        $GLOBALS['negativas'] = 0;
        $GLOBALS['positivas'] = 0;

        if($sinal == "- "){
            $GLOBALS['negativas'] = ($horas.':'.$minutos);
        }
        if($sinal == "+ "){
            $GLOBALS['positivas'] = ($horas.':'.$minutos);
        }

     //Retorna na tela as horas excedidas juntamente com o sinal + ou - em horas 
  /* (este return também já está correto, pois ele é a tabela que demonstrei
        anteriormente).*/
            return '<span style="color:'.$style.'">'.$sinal.$horas.':'.$minutos.'<input hidden value="'.$sinal.$horas.':'.$minutos.'"></span>';
```

3- Aqui, é o código que estou tentando realizar em tela para imprimir o total:

```
<?php //imprime as horas excedidas do dia
     echo $somatorio->horasExcedidasDia($intervals, $expediente,$registro->getDiaSemana(), $registro->getMarcacoes(), $funcionario->getHorario()->getId());
     $positivas = strtotime($GLOBALS['positivas']);
     $negativas += strtotime($GLOBALS['negativas']);

<td>+ <strong><?php echo date('H:i',$positivas) ?></strong></td>
<td colspan="2">- <strong><?php echo date('H:i', $negativas); ?></strong></td>
?>
```

4- Fiz um `var_dump` (apenas nas horas negativas) na tela para que vocês possam visualizar a soma que o PHP está fazendo (que por sinal está incorreto).

```
ID | Excedentes | VAR_DUMP |
1  |  - 03:00   | 03:00 ok |
2  |  + 00:14   |     -    |
3  |  + 00:20   |     -    |
4  |  - 01:24   | 08:24 err|
5  |  - 00:02   | 11:26 err|
6  |  + 00:01   |     -    |
---|------------|----------|
```

OBS: Os valores que estão na coluna EXCEDENTES, é exatamente os valores que estou passando para as globais.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O que acontece é que você está confundindo "horários" com "durações". Para entender melhor, considere as duas frases abaixo:

- o filme começa às duas horas da tarde
- o filme tem duração de duas horas

No primeiro caso, "duas horas" refere-se a um horário: a um **momento específico** do dia.

No segundo caso, "duas horas" refere-se a uma duração: a uma **quantidade de tempo**. Nesse caso, ela não diz quando o filme começa ou termina (nem se ele foi de fato exibido). Ela só diz a duração (quanto tempo ele dura), sem qualquer relação com algum horário específico.

O problema é que usamos as mesmas palavras (horas, minutos, etc) para ambos, mas eles são conceitos diferentes. Para piorar, até mesmo a forma de escrever pode ser igual: por exemplo, muitos cronômetros mostram `02:00` para indicar uma duração de duas horas.

---

Dito isso, [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) serve para lidar com datas (pontos específicos de um calendário) e horários (momentos específicos de um dia), mas não serve para trabalhar com durações.

Neste caso, você pode tratar os dados manualmente. Uma opção é calcular o total de minutos, e em seguida converter o resultado final em horas e minutos:

```
$tempos = [ '- 03:00', '+ 00:14', '+ 00:20', '- 01:24', '- 00:02', '+ 00:01' ];

$positivos = 0;
$negativos = 0;
foreach ($tempos as $t) {
    $v = explode(' ', $t);
    $campos = explode(':', $v[1]);
    $duracaoMinutos = ($campos[0] * 60) + $campos[1];
    if ($v[0] == '+') {
        $positivos += $duracaoMinutos;
    } elseif ($v[0] == '-') {
        $negativos += $duracaoMinutos;
    }
}

function formatar($duracaoMinutos) {
    $h = floor($duracaoMinutos / 60);
    $m = $duracaoMinutos % 60;
    return sprintf("%02d:%02d", $h, $m);
}

echo formatar($positivos); // 00:35
echo formatar($negativos); // 04:26
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, consegui compreender perfeitamente e ficou claro o entendimento do código e aplicação.

Answer (score 1):

Eu acredito que sua soma ocorre corretamente, mas na hora de mostrar o resutado, como você converte pra formato de data, ele faz confusão com os horários maiores que 24 horas. Tenta fazer as operações com horas/minutos separadamente e mostrar como texto mesmo

Comment: Cara acho que deu certo rsrsrs.
Porém precisei fazer algumas tratativas devido o minutos (não sei porque) estarem ultrapassando 60 minutos, fora isso parece ter resolvido!

Answer (score 0):

Apesar de já ter solução para questao, tive um pouco de dor de cabeça para resolver meu problema que calculo de saldo para um banco de horas, e gostaria de compartilhar minha solucao.

No sistema, fazemos lançamento de horas extras e compensações, gravando no banco de dados esses registros e tambem atualizando o saldo do banco de horas.

```
//>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ATUALIZAR SALDO BANCO HORAS >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>


//busca o saldo_banco_horas----------------------------------------------------------------------------
$consulta_saldo  = mysql_query("SELECT saldo_banco_horas FROM tb_banco_horas_saldo WHERE cod_funcionario = '$cod_funcionario'")or die("Error1:" .mysql_error());
$resultado_saldo = mysql_fetch_array($consulta_saldo);
$saldo_banco_horas = $resultado_saldo['saldo_banco_horas'];

//variaveis para teste---------
//$tipo_banco_horas = 'C';  //E (hora extra); C (compensacao)
//$saldo_banco_horas = "01:59";
//$qtd_horas = "00:45";

echo "saldo_banco: $saldo_banco_horas<br>";

//verifico o sinal do saldo, se positivo ou negativo
$sinal_saldo = $saldo_banco_horas[0];
echo "sinal_saldo: $sinal_saldo<br>";

echo "tipo_banco_horas: $tipo_banco_horas<br>";
echo "saldo_banco_horas: $saldo_banco_horas<br>";
echo "qtd_horas: $qtd_horas<p>";


//se já houver saldo cadastrado no banco de dados, faço os calculos -------------------------------------------------
if(mysql_num_rows($consulta_saldo)>0){

 //retiro o sinal de negativo, caso o saldo_banco_horas gravado seja negativo
 if($sinal_saldo == "-") $saldo = substr($saldo_banco_horas, 1);
 if($sinal_saldo != "-") $saldo = $saldo_banco_horas;
 echo "saldo  $saldo<p>";

 //transformo o saldo em segundos
 $partes_saldo = explode(':', $saldo);
 $segundos_saldo = $partes_saldo[0] * 3600 + $partes_saldo[1] * 60 + $partes_saldo[2];
 echo "segundos saldo: $segundos_saldo<p>";

 //transformo a qtd_horas(valor que esta sendo passado via formulario)  em segundos
 $partes_horas = explode(':', $qtd_horas);
 $segundos_horas = $partes_horas[0] * 3600 + $partes_horas[1] * 60 + $partes_horas[2];
 echo "segundos horas: $segundos_horas<p>";


 //se o saldo era negativo
 if($sinal_saldo == "-") {

  if($tipo_banco_horas == 'E'){
    $segundos = -$segundos_saldo + $segundos_horas;
  }

  if($tipo_banco_horas == 'C'){
    $segundos = -$segundos_saldo - $segundos_horas;
  }

  echo "segundos: $segundos<p>";

 }


 //se o saldo era positivo
 if($sinal_saldo != "-") {

  if($tipo_banco_horas == 'E'){
   $segundos = $segundos_saldo + $segundos_horas;
  }

  if($tipo_banco_horas == 'C'){
   $segundos = $segundos_saldo - $segundos_horas;
  }

  echo "segundos: $segundos<p>";

 }


 //funcao para converter segundos em horas novamente-----------------------------------------------------------
 function getFullHour($input) {
  $seconds = intval($input); //Converte para inteiro

  $negative = $seconds < 0; //Verifica se é um valor negativo

  if ($negative) {
   $seconds = -$seconds; //Converte o negativo para positivo para poder fazer os calculos
  }

  $hours = floor($seconds / 3600);
  $mins = floor(($seconds - ($hours * 3600)) / 60);
  $secs = floor($seconds % 60);

  $sign = $negative ? '-' : ''; //Adiciona o sinal de negativo se necessário

  return $sign . sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $mins, $secs);
 }//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 //echo getFullHour(685), PHP_EOL; //00:11:25
 //echo getFullHour(140801), PHP_EOL; //39:06:41
 //echo getFullHour(-140801), PHP_EOL; //-39:06:41

 $saldo_final = getFullHour($segundos);
 echo "saldo_final: $saldo_final<p>";


} //fecha mysql_num_rows($consulta_saldo)>0)



//se nao tiver saldo cadastrado no banco, saldo recebe qtd_horas informada
if(mysql_num_rows($consulta_saldo)<=0){

 if($tipo_banco_horas == 'E') $saldo_final =  $qtd_horas;
 if($tipo_banco_horas == 'C') $saldo_final =  "-".$qtd_horas;
 echo "saldo_final: $saldo_final<p>";

}
```